# Why doesn't the permission for a name work?

Tags: node.js, firebase, actions-on-google

I'm trying to allow a permission in Google Assistant, but the simulator just asks to "repeat the answer" when asking for a name. Here is the code for permission.

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
conv.ask(new Permission({
context: 'Hi there, to get to know you better',
permissions: 'NAME'
 }));
});
```

On deploying the code via Firebase, no errors are thrown.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your agent `Default Welcome Intent` is the intent which asks for `NAME` permission. 
You will have to implement another intent to handle this permission. Lets call it `user_info` intent.

So when Actions On Google asks the question, and the user responds “yes” or “no” (grants or declines); Actions On Google will then send an event called “actions_intent_PERMISSION” to DialogFlow. We’ll use that event to trigger this particular intent. Once the intent is triggered, we’ll make sure to send the “user_info” action to our application.

[image]

In the application, we’ll register the “user_info” action and make sure to check whether the user has granted or declined the permissions. For that, we call the isPermissionGranted helper method.

```
app.intent('user_info', (conv, params, permissionGranted) => {

  if (!permissionGranted) {
    throw new Error('Permission not granted');
  }

  const {requestedPermission} = conv.data;

  if (requestedPermission === 'NAME') {
    conv.user.storage.name = conv.user.name.display;
    return conv.close(responses.sayName(conv.user.storage.name));
  }

  throw new Error('Unrecognized permission');

});
```